# Is there a way to decode this PHP code?

Tags: php

I have this PHP code, and it appears to be obfuscated, instead of the massive line of code, I just substituted it with the word "code":

```
<?php
eval("?>".gzuncompress(base64_decode("code"))); ?>
```

Would there be any potential way of decoding said code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just replace the `eval()` with `echo()`. Based on experience, though, the code in there will probably be obfuscated as well.

Comment: But when I change it to echo all it prints is ?>  -- what do I do? When I click view source, it just has the source of the PHP file...

Comment: Look at the page's source in your browser.

Comment: Ah, I see. The page source was different. I just took that source and plugged it into a base64 decrypter and I got it working. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo gzuncompress(base64_decode("code")));
```

And, then, use auto format feature of some IDE