# How to view PHP code that is Base64 encoded and GZInflated?

Tags: php, base64, gzip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to decode this PHP code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907581/is-there-a-way-to-decode-this-php-code)
>   [What does this encoded string say, and how did you find out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612892/what-does-this-encoded-string-say-and-how-did-you-find-out)

So my client bought a Wordpress template and requires changes in what comes with the template. I figured out in which file the modifications need to be done, however the code in that file looks as follows:

```
<?php eval(gzinflate(base64_decode('[a bunch of alphanumerical values here'))); ?>
```

As I understand, this code is rendered on the spot, its encoded and compressed. However, I need to do modifications in there, so how would I go about obtaining an editable file out of that code?

If you care to know how I know it's the file that I need to edit, the translation file points to that file at a specific line to affect the copy.

Comment: By asking for it. The fact that they gave you an obfuscated template probably means they'll tell you "no", however.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace `eval()` with `echo` (mind the brackets), or by `file_put_contents('somefile.php', ....` to save raw script to `somefile.php` file.